# Getting unexpected newline when inserting JavaScript with PHP

Tags: php, javascript

I am trying to insert items into a javascript array for the autocomplete function.  I take the values that I need for the array from a database, so I grab them with PHP.  Then I just push each item into the javascript array.  However, it keeps telling me that I have an "unexpected token ILLEGAL" and it looks like it's pointing at the single "quote" character that gets inserted, then has a newline, then continues to the actual value.

My javascript/PHP

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
           var availableTags = [];
           <?php

              foreach ($modelList as &$model)
                 echo "availableTags.push('$model');" . "\n";
           ?>
           $("#devicemod").autocomplete({
                 source: availableTags
           });
        });


        </script>
```

Then the error message...

```
$(function() {
               var availableTags = [];
               availableTags.push('
***Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL***
ODEL: T]422P');availableTags.push('');availableTags.push('!');availableTags.push('!6.1/120{ MODEL: TM402P');availableTags.push('!A`$');availableTags.push('!DP1110   CREATED ON: JAN 29 2002');availableTags.push('!MODEL: TM402P');
```

It should turn out to be...

```
availableTags.push('ODEL:T]422P');
availableTags.push('');
etc...
```

Comment: Make sure your variable does not have any quotes. If it has, you will have to escape them.

Comment: You may also want to replace newlines with `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode) you can do this in a single (and safe) step:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   $("#devicemod").autocomplete({
       source: <?php echo json_encode($modelList); ?>
   });
});
</script>
```

The `json_encode()` function makes sure that the values are properly escaped according to the rules of JavaScript notation. This prevents nasty surprises when the values contain single quotes in this case.

If `$modelList` is not a true list (i.e. the keys are not numbered sequentially), you should apply [`array_values()`](http://php.net/array_values) first:

```php
...
       source: <?php echo json_encode(array_values($modelList)); ?>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bad idea:

```
   echo "availableTags.push('$model');" . "\n";
```

if `$model` contains ANY javascript metacharacters, particularly `'`, you'll introduce syntax errors and kill the entire `<script>` block. Never directly output arbitrary text into Javascript context - you're basically vulnerable to the JS equivalent of an [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com).

At bare minimum, you should be using `json_encode()` to guarantee that your text is syntactically valid for the context you're using it in:

```
echo 'availableTags.push(' . json_encode($model) . ");\n";
```

or better yet... why do all this pushing when youd could just generate an array automatically?

```
<?php
$data = array();
foreach ($modelList as $model) {
   $data[] = $model;
}
?>
var availableTags = <?php echo json_encode($data); ?>;
```